# How to append data to DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable` property.
The data is coming from the network in bulks.
Is there a way to tell `WPF` to append data to that grid without reloading the existing lines every time new data arrives?

I tried adding new rows to the `DataTable` and calling `DataGrid.Items.Refresh()` , but you can actually see the whole data gets reloaded every time new data arrives.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable} x:name="MyDataGrid"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
void NewDataArrived()
{
    foreach (var line in NewData)
    {
        MyDataTable.Rows.Add(line);
    }
    MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: What you mean by _but you can actually see the whole data gets reloaded every time new data arrives_? And `DataGrid.Items.Refresh()` just redraw control.

Comment: @Fabio I mean that after a few thousand lines have been added -  adding a few more lines makes the UI sluggish and unresponsive, as if it tried to clear the existing table and load the entire modified table to the DataGrid control. I was wondering if there's a way to tell the framework that the existing lines should be kept in the control and only a few lines should be added

Comment: How have you bound your data to the grid? If you use an `ObservableCollection` it *should* "just work".

Comment: @ChrisF XAML: DataSource="{Binding QueryResults, Mode=OneWay}"  C#: QueryResults.Rows.Add(...); ...;MyGrid.Items.Refresh(); (Let me know if it's not clear, I'll edit the question)

Comment: @Shmoopy, do not call `Refresh` method which will do exactly what you trying to avoid - redraw all rows

Comment: @Shmoopy - it's not clear. You should edit the question. What type is `QueryResults`, for example?

Comment: @Fabio Is there a better way to tell the control that new lines have been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bind your grid's `DataSource` to an `ObservableCollection` then when you add (or remove) items from that collection the grid will update for you.

Your XAML remains virtually the same:

```
DataSource="{Binding Results}"
```

But in your view model you have:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataType> Results
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

and when you read your data:

```
Results = new ObservableCollection(queryResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

is redundant. You should bind to a property that has OnPropertChanged in its setter:

```
public class DataGridViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
     private ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> _source;
        public ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> Source
        {
            get { return _source; }
            set
            {
                _source= value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
}
```

XAML:

```
   <DataGrid  Grid.Row="4"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
               AutoGenerateColumns="False"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Source, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

`ViewModelBase` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and instance of `DataGridViewModel` should be `DataContext` of your `DataGrid`.

`MyViewModel` should have default constructor if you want Adding Row in your Data Grid.